# Replace directory names in a path in ksh script

Tags: string, scripting, ksh

I want to produce a relative path from a given absolute path and store it in a variable.

`/aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd/eee.txt` should be producing `../../../..` which I can append to some other path as per the requirement.

`$filepath=/aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd/eee.txt`

I want to create a new variable called `$abs` which shall contain `../../../..`.

Tried this:

`echo "$filepath" | sed -r 's/*/../g'`

The above-said template is not working as per the requirement.

Being a newbie I might be asking foolish question.

Please excuse and thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't know what you will do with `${abs}` after `abs=$(some_command)`, it will be tricky using this relative path. Don't you want to find a `top_dir`, relative to your script, and express everything relative to this dir (like `inifile="${top_dir}/cfg/project.ini"`).

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure sed is capable of this but, can show an awk command that do it.

```
echo "$filepath" | awk -F'/' '{ for ( i = 2; i < NF-1; i++ ) printf "../" } END{print ".."}'
```

where 
`-F '/'` is the field separator
is separate the text `/aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd/eee.txt` into 6 sections, each section is can be used as a variable in awk, this also cause it remove field separator `/` in this case, from the text.

- `$1` is `''` empty as first / not have anything before it.
- `$2` is `aaa`
- `$3` is `bbb`
- `$4` is `ccc`
- `$5` is `ddd`
- `$6` is `eee.txt`

`NF` variable contain how many field we have.

---

`for ( i = 2; i < NF-1; i++ )` is for cycle

I start at 2 instead of 1 as first field is always empty, cause absolute path always start with `/` , this will ignore that field.

I also subtract `NF` variable with `1` as last field, will contain the file name, hence it is not a directory, however this allow a issue to happen if it is a directory and there is no `/` at the end of it like `/home/jondoe` you will end with `..` instead of `../..` while `/home/jondoe/` will work.

`printf "../"` get printed next to each other in each cycle as long for cycle is go.

`END{print ".."}` will print `..` regardless what happened is the input. This will cause the .. at the end of the text while for cycle only print `../` repeatedly

---

This command still can be improved to eliminate pitfalls, like the one I mentioned.
I hope this suit your needs.

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid escaping slashes with another character like `#`.
First you cut off the filename from the path with  "${filepath%/*}" (better than `basename`).
You replace every string with at least one character by dots.
And finally remove the starting slash.

```
echo "${filepath%/*}"| sed 's#[^/]\+#...#g;s#\/##'
```